# Should main effects and interaction terms be included in Kmeans clustering? (hierarchical principle in clustering analysis)

Tags: clustering, interaction, feature-selection, k-means

Let's say I'm trying to cluster observations based on five features, including:

- `n_emps`: Number of employees
- `n_cust`: Number of customers

If I were to declare `cust_per_emp` by dividing `n_cust` by `n_emps` to account for the average number of customers per employee, would it make sense to keep all five features plus the new one, or should I drop `n_emps` and `n_cust`, leaving the three original features plus the new one?

In other words, in clustering analysis is there something like the hierarchical principle of additive models? For instance, in linear regression, it would be recommended to leave `n_emps`, `n_cust` and `cust_per_emp`.

However, in KMeans, if two observations have similar values for `n_emps` and `n_cust`, then they should have simliar values for `cust_per_emp` as well.